# Share multiple pictures on Facebook in one post

Tags: android, facebook

I it possible to share a few pictures in on post on Facebook?

I am using thin code:

```
parameters.putByteArray("picture", data);
parameters.putByteArray("picture1", data);   // IS this possible?
response = facebook.request("me/photos", parameters, "POST"); 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a Photo Album and post as many photos you want to the use's album.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/album